# Merge Files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My usecase is to merge all CSV files in S3 to a single CSV file,
I have explored MultipartUpload but its for files >5MB

File size for my usecase is not greater than 50B and the number of CSV files are in the range 10^7

what is the best possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential way to do this would be to use **Amazon Athena**. It can query multiple files within a given path and can output results. So, it's really just doing a `SELECT *` on the data and giving you the result, rather than "merging".

The steps would be:

- In Athena, use `CREATE TABLE` to identify the format and location of the input data
- Configure an Output Location for Athena
- Run `SELECT * FROM table`, which will query all of the CSV files and store the output in the specified location
- You could then copy the output file to where you would like to store the 'merged' data

See: [Working with Query Results, Output Files, and Query History - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html)